# Bootstrap styling not working on devise views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I cannot tell what I am doing wrong but bootstrap is not styling devise even though I have imported it.

app/views/users/session/new.html.erb

```
    <h2>Sign up here</h2>

    <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" required: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

app/assets/stylesheets/style.css.scss

```
    @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
    @import "bootstrap";
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
/*
     * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
     * listed below.
     *
     * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
     * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
     *
     * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
     * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
     * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
     * file per style scope.
     *
     *= require_tree .
     *= require_self
     */
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: show me application.css file

Comment: you are using twitter bootstrap  https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails , and adding bootstrap in your css file. could you re check your syntax with twitter-bootstrap-rails link also look on to it http://www.octolabs.com/blogs/octoblog/2013/01/17/styling_devise_with_twitter_bootstrap/